# How to increase CPU cache on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: cpu-mining, hashrate, raspberry-pi

I'm mining some Monero on my raspberry pi (Of course only for educational purposes). In order to increase my hashrate I'd like to increase my CPU cache. I already searched SE but haven't found a solution/tutorial so far...

Do you know how to increase my CPU cache?

Any help would be very appreciated!!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't think you can, that's on the chip.  You can tweak RAM splits CPU/GPU in raspi-conf.  But don't think you will get any changes to L1 L2 caches.  (Actually hope I'm wrong)

Comment: You cannot increase CPU cache without using a different CPU.

Comment: Other note:  Look for a SBC (Single Board Computer) like a Beaglebones OrangePis etc. that has AES on the chip (not sure if any of those doe have the onboard AES, but that is whats needed for reasonable performance).  That's the key to improved performance (from what I've read)  The Pi doesn't have that.  In all honesty, the Pi (have like 20 of them) isn't a great SBC for number.  crunching.  (great for other stuff)  For what its worth I do run a full node monerod on an OrangePi zero 512MB.  It runs better then on a RPi3. (but the OPi is a Arm7 over RPi's Arm6 and OPi's true Ehternet port)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't increase the CPU cache... For faster CPU performance a better CPU should be used.

Using a higher swapsize could be interesting but doesn't affect the CPU cache nor the hashrate...

Comment: swapsize won't affect mining performance.